# Entity Framework v6.1 query compilation performance

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, linqpad

I am confused how EF LINQ queries are compiled and executed. When I run a piece of program in LINQPad couple of times, I get varied performance results (each time the same query takes different amount of time). Please find below my test execution environment.

tools used: EF v6.1 & LINQPad v5.08. 
Ref DB : ContosoUniversity DB downloaded from MSDN.

For queries, I am using Persons, Courses & Departments tables from the above DB; see below.

[image]

Now, I have below data:

[image]

Query goal: get the second person and associated departments.
Query:

```
var test = (
    from p in Persons
    join d in Departments on p.ID equals d.InstructorID 
    select new {
       person = p,
       dept = d
    }
);

var result = (from pd in test
    group pd by pd.person.ID into grp
    orderby grp.Key 
    select new {
          ID = grp.Key,
          FirstName = grp.First().person.FirstName,
          Deps = grp.Where(x => x.dept != null).Select(x => x.dept).Distinct().ToList()
         }).Skip(1).Take(1).ToList();

   foreach(var r in result)
   {
        Console.WriteLine("person is..." + r.FirstName);
        Console.WriteLine(r.FirstName + "' deps are...");
        foreach(var d in r.Deps){
           Console.WriteLine(d.Name);
        }
   }
```

When I run this I get the result and LINQPad shows time taken value from 3.515 sec to 0.004 sec (depending how much gap I take between different runs).

If I take the generated SQL query and execute it, that query always runs between 0.015 sec to 0.001sec.

Generated query:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1
DECLARE @p1 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t7].[ID], [t7].[value] AS [FirstName]
FROM (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t6].[ID]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t6].[ID],   [t6].[value]
     FROM (
       SELECT [t2].[ID], (
         SELECT [t5].[FirstName]
          FROM (
            SELECT TOP (1) [t3].[FirstName]
            FROM [Person] AS [t3]
            INNER JOIN [Department] AS [t4] ON ([t3].[ID]) = [t4].    [InstructorID]
            WHERE [t2].[ID] = [t3].[ID]
            ) AS [t5]
        ) AS [value]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t0].[ID]
        FROM [Person] AS [t0]
        INNER JOIN [Department] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[ID]) = [t1].[InstructorID]
        GROUP BY [t0].[ID]
        ) AS [t2]
      ) AS [t6]
  ) AS [t7]
WHERE [t7].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
ORDER BY [t7].[ROW_NUMBER]
GO

-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @x1 Int = 2
-- EndRegion
SELECT DISTINCT [t1].[DepartmentID], [t1].[Name], [t1].[Budget], [t1].    [StartDate], [t1].[InstructorID], [t1].[RowVersion]
FROM [Person] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Department] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[ID]) = [t1].[InstructorID]
WHERE @x1 = [t0].[ID]
```

My questions: 
1) Are those LINQ statements correct? Or can they be optimized?
2) Is the time difference for LINQ query execution normal?

Another different question:
I have modified the first query to execute immediately (called ToList before the second query). This time generated SQL is very simple as shown below (it doesn't look like there is a SQL query for the first LINQ statement with ToList() included):

```
 SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[LastName], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[HireDate], [t0].      [EnrollmentDate], [t0].[Discriminator], [t1].[DepartmentID], [t1].[Name], [t1].   [Budget], [t1].[StartDate], [t1].[InstructorID], [t1].[RowVersion]
 FROM [Person] AS [t0]
 INNER JOIN [Department] AS [t1] ON ([t0].[ID]) = [t1].[InstructorID]
```

Running this modified query also took varied amount of time but the difference is not as big as the first query set run.

In my application, there going to be lot of rows and I prefer first query set to second one but I am confused.

Please guide.
(Note: I have a little SQL Server knowledge so, I am using LINQPad to fine tune queries based on the performance)

Thanks

Comment: Are you seeing the same execution time for the generated SQL Query even if you haven't run the LINQ code before? 
There could be caching in SQL Server involved in your response times

Comment: When your queries go beyond the trivial, like yours have, its probably better to write the SQL you want, test it in SQL Server Management Studio, and then call the SQL in your code. Linq is an "expression of desire" and not a SQL replacement, so if you want a complex outcome its probably best to use the native SQL language (my opinion). In terms of measuring SQL performance, stopwatching on LinqPad is not giving you consistency - use SQL Profiler which will tell you the Logical IO and CPU Time of the SQL and is independent of caching artefacts.

Comment: @Jonny: I agree SQL Server would be caching but I guess that will be applicable to both the scenarios: running with and without those LINQ statements unless LINQ generates different SQL queries each time which is not the case. I am not comparing execution run duration values between direct SQL & LINQ statements but only LINQ statements.

Comment: @PhillipH : I don't know much about SQL queries. So, I am using LINQ queries. But when complicated queries are required, I agree with you - using direct SQL statements; if maintenance becomes a headache, we should use SPs.

Comment: @CHEMBETIARAVIND Caching would normally give you a longer first execution time and then a shorter time the next time you run the same query. Overall load could also complicate this